# edit text not accepting numbers , accepts only alphabets (no input type is set)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

```
<TextView
    style="@style/ProductTextViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Add a Price at a Local Store" />

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/store_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/store"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/stores_hint" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/no_prices_found"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/price_italic_hint" >

    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add price"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</TableRow>
```

The edit text with id ="no_prices_found" does not accept any numbers but accepts special characters and alphabets . Any clue on this weird behavior of edit text in android. The "store" named edit text behaves properly .

===== NOTE ====== 
This layout works fine when it is used as fragment layout which is used in its parent fragment .Any idea what behavior of parent could cause this ?

Comment: Do you set any properties in code?

Comment: Nothing at all . No request focus , input type etc

Comment: The only difference I see is that you use a closing /> for one, and </edittext> for the other, but that should not matter. Try cutting the xml of the one that is wrong, save, and ten paste it back.

Comment: What do you mean `works fine when it is used as fragment layout`? Can you please also post the entire layout file?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069507/edittext-does-not-accept-digits-as-input

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem when my EditText was placed inside a Dialog layout and I was not able to type any digits inside the field (letters and other characters did work just fine), changing the inputType did not help.

I realised that I use custom OnKeyListener for my Dialog and that was the problem - false must be returned from inside in case the pressed key should be passed to Dialog's children (including EditText) properly. Then my EditText started working again as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem was in consuming the event in OnKeyListener when the criteria were not met (the key pressed was not enter). This led to not passing onKey event to the system. Returning `false` did the job.

More on Android Event Handling you can find [here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_and_Example_of_Android_Event_Handling)