# EditText does not accept digits as input

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-edittext

The `EditText` view with `id="price"` has an `inputType="numberDecimal"` that does not accept any digits but will only accept one decimal point.  The other `EditText` view with `id="store"` has no `inputType` set but has two issues.  If the view has no input then entering a digit from the keyboard doesn't do anything.  The only way to have a digit be accepted is if it immediately follows either a letter or another digit.  I am using the default `Android` keyboard.  The layout is being inflated in the `onCreateView()` method of a subclass of `SherlockFragment`.  Could this be an issue with the `EditText` view behavior inside a `SherlockFragment`?  I have a similar layout that is used to inflate a subclass of 'SherlockFragmentActivity', and those `EditText` views behave normally.  Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        style="@style/ProductTextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:text="Product Tile" />
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="50dp"     
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView 
              style="@style/ApolloStyleBold"
              android:layout_width="0dp" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:layout_weight="0.4"
              android:gravity="center_vertical" 
              android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
              android:text="@string/price"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/price" 
                  android:layout_width="0dp" 
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="0.6" 
                  android:background="@null" 
                  android:hint="@string/price_italic_hint"
                  android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="50dp"    
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView   
            style="@style/ApolloStyleBold"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
            android:text="@string/store_name"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/store" 
                  android:layout_width="0dp" 
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="0.6" 
                  android:background="@null" 
                  android:hint="@string/stores_hint"
        />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

## Update

When I tested this on Android v4.3, it has the messed up (not accepting digits as input) behavior.  However, I tested it on Android v4.1.2, and it accepts digits as input.  Is there something different about these two versions as far as EditText behavior?

Comment: Re: your update. You may want to file a bug report. I only see one similar question here, and it is pretty recent also

Comment: Curious: Does removing the hint have any effect?

Comment: Just tested this exact on 4.3 with a standard `Activity` and I am not seeing the problem you describe.

Comment: If it has to do with version differences, then it may be that 4.3 has new text traversal.  "Text traversal in accessibility now gives you more control – choose to move between pages, paragraphs, lines, words or characters."

Comment: I tested it on two 4.3 devices (new Nexus 7 and Nexus 10) in a SherlockFragment, views inflated in the onCreateView(), using the stock Android keyboard and it worked flawlessly on both devices. I wonder if this has to to with the styles you apply to the TextViews? Maybe you can post those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the issue wasn't with the `android:inputType` that was set, but with a ViewGroup higher up in the view hierarchy.  The layout which is used to inflate the `SherlockFragment` was a child in a more complex layout.

A few parents up the view hierarchy there was a subclass of the `FrameLayout` ViewGroup called `DragLayer`.  The `DragLayer` class implemented an `Interface` called `DragController.DragListener` which has a method `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`.  This method in `DragLayer` uses the `@Override` notation however did not call `super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)`.  After adding this line of code, then the event of clicking a digit on the keyboard did not get consumed and all works now.

Comment: Phew! This helped me out so much. In my case, the ScrollView subclass (from this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114179/4102858) that I was imbedding my EditText in was causing the problem.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about using this solution? I didn't quite undrestand the way you've suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code in price edittext

```
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"  // this means number or decimal
```

Comment: Hey @MrCoom1qSooN, I tried setting this inputType you have suggested, but am seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

I think you should have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the code below on your EditText xml:

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

This tells your EditText to accept only these digits. Of course you can modify it to whatever you need.

Comment: Hey @Herrera, I also tried your suggestion and it doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `android:numeric="integer|signed|decimal"`?
Alternatively, you can set the `KeyListener` with `setKeyListener()` method, and force the `EditText` to accept the number/punct/character.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on my emulator. But there is a small thing which might be the answer to your problem, please input the digits from the number keys at the top of the character keys  of your keyboard. Please do not use your numeric keyboard of the computers keyboard to enter the numbers. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm testing this out on a device.  And with the inputType set to numberDecimal it doesn't show the number keys at the top of the character keys.

Comment: Add this to your editext from java code. This shows numeric only, with no option to enter text values.                                                                                        editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);